# How do I change the size of my ad banner from 320px wide to 480px wide?

Tags: iphone, iad

1- my app is only runs on landscape mode, so i set the size of my AdBannerVioew to 480x32 but when i load the app, and i see the "test ad" it doesn't cover the width of the screen, and it's only 320px wide, is it because it's not an actual ad, and it's just for test?

2- I don't want to show the ad all the timer, every 3 minutes i want to show the ad for about 15 seconds and then hide it, would apple approve this?

Comment: Only Apple knows what they'll approve and what they won't. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the AdBannerView to 480x32 programatically?

```
myAdBannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32;
```

Apple would probably approve of you showing your ad only for a little bit, but your revenue will vary if you're hiding and showing the ad. [Here's the official documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881)

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator