# Xcode - iAd Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iad, adbannerview

I added an AdBannerView in a Storyboard but if I run the app I get an error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content
```

the whole error:

```
[AppDeveloper] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x7fd86afdf330 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display test IAd banner in the simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator)

Comment: Can you give us more info?  Is that the whole error?

Comment: Did you hook up the banner view properly?  It seems that this error is telling you you have a banner but it does not get filled with content because it's not hooked up right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to include ADBannerViewDelegate in your Swift file? And after that it seems the error is saying that you have not implemented

```
func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!)
```

After that make sure to connect your banner view's delegate to the class your view is so that it can handle the error using the above function.